# please help error to reinstall my system launcher

Tags: adb

okay so what happened, Im using a poco x3 nfc and I wanted to use full screen gestures on 3rd party launchers, I followed a guide which led me to using windows powershell, I was trying to install a lower version of the system launcher which is poco launcher through the code
`.\adb install -d apkname` and I keep getting a `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER` error.

So i tried looking it up on google and how to fix it, the solution I found was to delete the app, since the poco launcher is an system app I couldn't delete the system on the phone itself so i tried deleting it through adb, i looked up how to delete a file using the `adb shell` and `pm uninstall –k –user 0 package name` command which worked, Im not sure how it worked but the poco launcher is now gone, but when I tried the `.\adb install -d apkname` command I keep getting the same `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER` error, Im not used to messing around this deep with phone tech and just I just desperately want to install the default poco launcher again and return things back to normal.

guide I was trying to follow:
https://youtu.be/fBn3kNGEE1s

Comment: "I followed a guide" - when talking about external tutorials please always include at least the link to the tutorial.